# How to re-order the number after write a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

so i have a list/array in python code. So this is the code :

```
array = ["Jouzu", "Julio", "Jovana",["Jo","Ju","Jopa"]]
array.insert(3,"Arisman")
array[4].extend(["Aki","Nini"])
del array[4][3:]
array.append(["Aki","Nini"])
array[4].insert(0,"Papa")
array[4].insert(1,"Mama")
array.insert(5,"Moch. Arifandi")
array.insert(6,"Siti Aisyah")
array.insert(4,"Ine Pranina")
print(array)

for nomor, member in enumerate(array):
    if member == array[5]:
        continue
    elif member == array[8]:
        break
    print(nomor,member)
```

But after i print out, something odd show up

```
['Jouzu', 'Julio', 'Jovana', 'Arisman', 'Ine Pranina', ['Papa', 'Mama', 'Jo', 'Ju', 'Jopa'], 'Moch. Arifandi', 'Siti Aisyah', ['Aki', 'Nini']]
0 Jouzu
1 Julio
2 Jovana
3 Arisman
4 Ine Pranina
6 Moch. Arifandi
7 Siti Aisyah
```

yeah, i remove the 2 items in list but i want to re order the number back again so it should be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: You are printing the index of the array as you iterate. If you want to gain new indexes, with the items removed. You should store the result of your iteration in a new array, then your indexes will match your desired output.

Answer (score -1):

```
i = 0
for member in array:
    if member == array[5]:
       continue
    elif member == array[8]:
       break
    print(i, member)
    i += 1
```